# How can I solve a "Version Error" when trying to run rdiff-backup between the latest Ubuntu release and the latest Security Onion release?

Tags: 20.04, security, versions, rdiff-backup

Background information / previous post available here: [Need to try to install a specific package version -- however apt-cache madison, apt-cache policy only seem to list the latest version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274699/need-to-try-to-install-a-specific-package-version-however-apt-cache-madison), though I don't think it'll be particularly necessary or helpful to read.

I was trying to run rdiff-backup, which failed as [shown here](https://imgur.com/a/nHKevSY). The issue seems to be that Security Onion (I'm told) runs on an older version of Ubuntu, limiting it's rdiff-backup version / repo available to 1.2.8, whereas the latest version of Ubuntu is running 2.0.0 (if I recall the exact version number correctly, which I think I do.)

Now I pretty much got the answers I was hoping for as far as playing with apt-get install and being able to download a specific version -- but somebody recommended I post this as it's own question, so I wanted to follow suit in case it yielded any helpful answers.

As of now, my workaround is just to install an older Ubuntu version; since for my strictly homework purposes, it doesn't matter what OS I rdiff-backup to, just that I backup to a different box with it.

Comment: Can you explain your use case / what you are trying to do? If you are using a computer with a supported version of Ubuntu installed your question may be on topic but right now it does not look that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share installed libraries between Debian and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911155/share-installed-libraries-between-debian-and-ubuntu)

Comment: I'm just making this post bc someone said this would be a better question :( didn't think it merited downvotes or anything.

Comment: And karel; no this isn't really what I was asking about. But thank you for trying. Can anyone explain why this question is being downvoted or poorly received? I'm not sure I understand why. Like I said, a poster in my previous question told me my PRIOR question was bad, and that this would have been better to ask -- despite the original post asking precisely what I was curious about.

Comment: When you want to make this work on a newer Ubuntu version (20.04 in my case), I found the answer above did not work for me, so I asked the question - and got an answer that did work here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388614/

Answer (score 1):

In case the remote-server/destination-server is running an old version 1.2.8* and the local-server/source-server in running the new 2.0* version rdiff-backup will not work.

```
...
version of rdiff-backup is quite different from the local version (2.0.0).
```

In order to solve this issue with the differences, both the (source-server) and the (destination-server) must be in the same major versions (1.2.x).

The solution is: (tested and worked fine for me)

```
sudo su 
echo 'deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rdiff-backup-1-2-8-pkgs-ubuntu.list

apt install -y librsync1=0.9.7-10build1 rdiff-backup=1.2.8-7
```

Confirm the installation version :

```
rdiff-backup --version
```

With that source and destination servers with the same version the cms for using rdiff-backups should be fine:

```
rdiff-backup /PATH backups-server::/path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python 3 version available from the PyPI repository.

First check that your current rdiff-backup came from apt repositories:

```
apt-cache policy rdiff-backup
```

Then remove it using apt.

```
sudo apt remove rdiff-backup
```

If not yet present, install pip3:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

And finally install the rdiff-backup 2.0.0 version:

```
sudo pip3 install rdiff-backup==2.0.0
```